# Highcharts - Where is the location of 'back to {series.name}' in Yii2?

Tags: php, highcharts, yii2

Does anyone know where the ***back to {series.name}*** button's location? I want to edit it to be ***back to previous***
[image]

I'm using this:

```
use miloschuman\highcharts\HighchartsAsset;
    use yii\helpers\Url;
    use yii\helpers\Html;
    use yii\bootstrap\Dropdown;
    HighchartsAsset::register($this)->withScripts(['modules/exporting', 'modules/drilldown']);  
    $this->title = 'Highcharts Test';
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/0hzhthbx/ check this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change this by setting [Highcharts options > lang > drillUpText](http://api.highcharts.com/highmaps/lang.drillUpText).